# Call a JavaScript function from an HTML button when clicked and change variable value

Tags: javascript, html

The code I currently have is not working, and it seems to be because of the `if` statement as if I remove it, it works great, but then it doesn't do what I need, obviously.

What is wrong with this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="sample0" onclick="javascript:setval(0)" />
</body>

<script>
    var mysample = 0;

    function setval(varval) {
        mysample = varval;
        alert(mysample);
    }

    if (mysample = 0) {
        alert("GET OFF MY LAWN");
    }
</script>

<body>
    <marquee id="Marquee1">Hello</marquee>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysample = 0` is *setting* mysample to be 0 and then returning 0 so the if statement fails. You want to *test* equality which requires two or three `=` signs. Try `if( mysample === 0 )`

Answer (score 1):

The condition in your if statment in

Try

```
if(mysample === 0)
```

You can see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) documentation on the use of logical operators in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This `if(mysample = 0)` will always return true and make mysample as 0. Use `===` to check.